# What is the deno equivalent of node --check

Tags: deno

In node there is a --check option to check if code is valid for execution without actually running it if valid.
I have been looking for an equivalent in deno (deno help, deno run help, deno lint help)

The closest i can figure out is `deno lint`, but it will happily lint the following typescript code (in test.ts), which `deno run` subsequently refuses to run (obviously).

What is the canonical deno "dry run"?

test.ts:

```
const message = "hello!";
message();
```

Comment: `node --check` only does a syntax check, so your `test.ts` would pass that too...

Comment: @FZs Note that the question is about *typescript*, hence the .ts extension. The code is valid javascript, not typescript

Comment: In lieu of a better answer, i guess one can use `deno compile -o /dev/null <script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check if code is valid for execution

> "dry run"

These concepts don't exist. I think what you want is to have your TypeScript code analyzed using static type-checking (without actually running the module). This is called *compilation* and the Deno subcommand you want in this case is [`cache`](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/command_line_interface#cache-and-compilation-flags):

```
deno cache module.ts
```

Re-cache the entrypoint module and all dependencies:

```
deno cache --reload module.ts
```

Using your example `test.ts`:

```
% deno cache test.ts
Check file:///Users/deno/test.ts
error: TS2349 [ERROR]: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.
message();
~~~~~~~
    at file:///Users/deno/test.ts:2:1
```